# what is the effective address of this instruction?

Tags: assembly, x86-16

Initially BX=0x0100, num1=0x1001, [num1]=0x0000, and SI=0x0100

```
a. mov ax, [bx+12]
b. mov ax, [bx+num1] 
c. mov ax, [num1+bx] 
d. mov ax, [bx+si]
```

if someone recommend me to learn assembly language from basic with many examples that would be good

i am confuse how to calculate this

now i think is that i have to first convert hex value of bx into binary then decimal then add 12 and whatever value come i convert it back and write the answer like this

```
 mov ax,[answer];
```

so this is correct or wrong??

Comment: Look at the addressing modes of x86 assembler and then figure out which is being used in each case. Also, learn hex arithmetic - it's really not that hard and saves a lot of time (eg 12=0x0C, +4=0x10) .

Comment: yes you should learn hex arithmetic

Answer (score 2):

If you only want to figure out the address, just do the math in base 16:

- a. `bx+12` = `0x100 + 0xc` = `0x10c`
- b. `bx+num1` = `0x100 + 0x1001` = `0x1101`
- c. `num1+bx` = `0x1001 + 0x100` = `0x1101`
- d. `bx+si` = `0x100 + 0x100` = `0x200`

Comment: so first answer will be like this mov ax,[0x10c] or ax,0x10c  which one?

Comment: and c mean constant  James  ??

Comment: @tjnapster555 `[bx+12]` is the same as `[0x10c]`, `mov ax,[0x10c]` moves the `word` located at address `0x10c` into register `ax`. `mov ax, 0x10c` moves the value `0x10c` into register `ax`. `0xc` is hexadecimal for `12`

Comment: can you recommend a book for assembly language for 8086 architecture programing

Comment: @tjnapster555 Perhaps (and i recommend based solely on my opinion) [Assembly Language step by step](http://www.amazon.ca/Assembly-Language-Step-Step-Programming/dp/0471375233) which covers 16 bit 8086 programming primarily in `DOS`. I read the newer edition of this book when i first started learning assembly, it covers 32 bit 80386 style of programming in `Linux` exclusively, both the books give a really good background for assembly in the first few chapters, the second chapter covers number bases including __Arithmetic in Hex__.